# Search for text inside decompiled classes using JD and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler

I'm currently trying to debug an issue with our web application - I can see an error message in the logs but I can't tell where it originates, though I suspect it's coming from one of the classes provided by the closed-source ecommerce platform we use.

I have the JD-Eclipse decompiler - is there some way I can search for a piece of text contained in one of the compiled classes through Eclipse?

Comment: You can download JD-GUI (http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-gui) open the jar file who containst the class and then search from the toolbar.

Comment: Yep, I've used that method before. I was hoping there was a way to do this in Eclipse though...

Comment: @vzamanillo if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it if nothing better is suggested.

Comment: Ok, I was trying to find a solution with JD-eclipse, thank you rcgeorge23.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-gui) open the jar file who containst the class and then search from the toolbar.

**Update:**

[Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten) is a better and modern alternative to JD (thanks, Antimony)

Comment: JD is pretty old. I'd recommend using Luyten instead.

Comment: Luyten is very nice.  However, it doesn't decompile .war files, whereas JD-GUI does.

Comment: Also, it appears Luyten does not have global search.  JD-GUI does.